# excel convert picture to number in multiple cells

Tags: image, excel, numbers

I have an xlsx file that has a bunch of pictures (of check marks, downloaded from an Oracle survey), that I would like to convert to a number, or even text, for data analysis.  All the pictures have different names, but they are effectively all the same image.  Regardless of the image, I would like to insert a 1 if the image is present, and leave blank or insert 0 if no image (so maybe there is an if/then statement for this??). There are lots of hits for converting text to a picture, but not this other way around! Any help?  Thanks!

Comment: To convert the picture to a number we need to know how to associate the pictures to worksheet cells.  Is each picture located within a specific cell??

Comment: You can loop through the sheet's `Shapes` collection, checking the `TopLeftCell` property of each shape - if it corresponds to a cell of interest then put 1 in that cell.